# Where is the kernel source for a cross-complied kernel rpi

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, source

I have cross-compiled and installed the Linux kernel with the real-time patch, version 3.18.16-rt13-v7+, on a raspberrypi but then I can't find the current kernel source in `/usr/src`. Then I tried the following, without success:

```
pi@raspberrypi:$ sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree

 Reading state information... Done
 E: Unable to find a source package for linux-image-3.18.16-rt13-v7+
```

I need the kernel source in order to compile and install the Etherlab-master.

Comment: You shouldn't use `sudo` for `apt-get source`.

Comment: What command(s) did you use to deploy the kernel onto the RPi? It would usually only copy over the binary files and wouldn't copy the source code ; but you built it yourself, so you have all the source available, why can't you just copy it over?

Comment: Also, take a closer look at the Etherlab `./configure` part, you can provide options there, things like the Linux source code location and you might even be able to cross-compile it on a PC before deploying it on the RPi, it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

If there is not a `/usr/src` directory on your system, then the kernel source has not been installed. The easiest way to do this is by running:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
```

**Update**

Download the Latest Stable Kernel from [kernel_archive](https://www.kernel.org/)
 unrar the kernel source

```
tar -xvJf linux-x.y.z.tar.xz
```

Configure the Kernel
First , install `libncurses & libncurses-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses libncurses-dev
```

then

```
cd linux-x.y.z
make menuconfig
```

to use the default config select **save** to save the config in the file name .config

Compile and install

```
make
make modules
make modules_install
make install
```

Reboot your system

Comment: This won't do much in case you built a custom kernel.

Comment: @fduff He need only the kernel source , i will update